# 404 converted to success in JQuery forms ajaxSubmit

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

My options to $(form).ajaxSubmit(...) include:

```
    type : "post",
    dataType : "text",
```

no jsonp. No json, even.

However, there is a file upload. This causes jquery forms to use an iframe, which I suspect is the source of my problem. To whit: when my service returns 404 from the post (which I can see in the chrome dev tools), my success function is called.

I'm using jquery 1.7. I've tried the global statusCode handler suggested by 3nigma, it's not called.

Is there any way to catch the actual HTTP status code in this case?

Relevant Plugins in use:

- malsup's jquery forms (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) -- no version number in the file.
- jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.0

**UPDATE**

Updating to very latest jquery.form.js fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a global default in [`ajaxsetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      console.log('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? Does the global code end up executing 'inside' the iframe or something?

Comment: the `ajaxSetup` will act as a default for every ajax request, if your calling code `$.ajax({..})` resides in the parent window then it will be executed in the parent window not in the iframe.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that this didn't work in chrome. No call to the global status code function. I'm going to move the $.ajaxSetup to make absolutely sure that it's executed in the right scope ... and calling it in the document-ready handler didn't work either.

Comment: so the problem was not really with the ajax `:)`

Comment: Indeed, and I can't easily explain how the one messed up the other.